# python web crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - web crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059691/python-web-crawling)

The last question was closed as it was "ambiguous". So i'll try to be specific here:

Consider this website :
http://www.tripadvisor.in/

and the reviews given at the bottom, 
I need to be able to open the profile of the reviewer, and extract information like age, sex and location if it is public.

A step-by-step process on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

PS : Is this do-able using scrapy ?

UPDATE : Assuming I have a database with the names of the users and i can directly open the member's profile for example, for Lulak

http://www.tripadvisor.in/members/Lulak

How do i extract the Age, sex and location from this page

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) in combination with beautifulsoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) . Might be a alternative to scrapy

Comment: This is doable using scrapy. Check the documentation here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html

Comment: Both mechanize and scrapy have reasonably straightforward tutorials. Try working through those first and posting questions if you get stuck.

Comment: I just finished the scrapy tutorial. I am looking at the source code using inspect element at the website but can't figure out how to extract the information.

Comment: What's wrong with the links posted in the comments of your previous question? (http://pravin.insanitybegins.com/posts/writing-a-spider-in-10-mins-using-scrapy)

This will teach you, step by step, how to scrap a website. Then all you need to is to adapt it to the website you want. 

Are you expecting someone to write the code for the problem you have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll get better answers if you post specific programming questions along the lines of "here is what I've tried; I expected X but got Y". For tutorials, you're better off using a search engine.

Comment: @super9 The link you gave isn't working. No I was just hoping for someone to tell me the elements to be extracted because while using the inspect element I couldn't find the exact element to use while extracting those data !

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried and the error you're getting?

Comment: Here is the correct link for the blog post @super9 wanted to link - http://pravin.insanitybegins.com/posts/writing-a-spider-in-10-mins-using-scrapy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through two of their profile pages, I found that this div contains the personal info

```
<div id="amd" style="display: block">
```

And the `id` amd isn't used in any where else, so you can narrow your search to this particular div. After that, it is just a simple case of searching for the relevant information. You just need to find the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags -

```
<dt>Location:</dt> <dd>Switzerland</dd>
```

I think you can handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is absolutely possible with Scrapy. If you're just opening a list of URLs that you know rather than scraping the site it I'd say Scrapy is overkill.

I would recommend [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for HTML parsing, it's simple and considerably faster than BeautifulSoup (can be as much as two orders of magnitude). And [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for HTTP because it's super simple.

In the snippet below I'm using an XPath query to find the correct definition description element. `//dl[dt/text()='term']//dd/text()` is essentially saying "find the definition list (dl) element that has a definition term with text content of 'term' (`//dl[dt/text()='term']`) and then find all definition description (dd) elements and get their text content (`//dd/text()`)".

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import requests
from lxml import etree

response = requests.get("http://www.tripadvisor.in/members/SomersetKeithers")

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(response.text), parser)

def get_definition_description(tree, term):
  description = tree.xpath("//dl[dt/text()='%s']//dd/text()" % term)
  if len(description):
    return description[0].strip()

print get_definition_description(tree, "Age:")
print get_definition_description(tree, "Gender:")
print get_definition_description(tree, "Location:")
```